# Java Web Services - Defining Server Location

Tags: java, web-services, annotations

I have one final hurdle to get over with the web services application I am working with; I need to be able to override the default settings used to set the schema location and soap address location in the generated WSDL file.

When I deploy the application (GlassFish v2.1 on Red Hat linux) it uses the local server name in the URLs but it needs to use the public domain name instead. I was able to save the WSDL file locally, change the URLs, make it public, generate a test application externally from the file, and lastly was able to successfully run a test.

I have now journeyed into the realm of JAX-WS custom bindings but I'm hoping that I either overlooked a simpler solution or the bindings are not as complicated as they look at first glance. The web service implementation is through a stateless EJB (e.g. MyWS.java below). The generated WSDL file would look like MyWSDL.wsdl (see below).

In the xsd:import tag I need to change schemaLocation to

```
    http://test.mycompany.com/MyWSService/MyWS?xsd=1
```

instead of

```
    http://local-server-name/MyWSService/MyWS?xsd=1
```

and in the soap:address tag I need to change location to be

```
    http://test.mycompany.com/MyWSService/MyWS
```

instead of

```
    http://local-server-name/MyWSService/MyWS.
```

**MyWS.java**

```
@WebService(name="MyWS",
        portName="MyWSPort",
        serviceName="MyWSService",
        targetNamespace="http://test.mycompany.com/")
@Stateless()
public class MyWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName="testLogin")
    public String testLogin(@WebParam(name="username") String username,
            @WebParam(name="password") String password) {
        String retVal = "Test Failed.";

        //do some stuff

        return retVal;
    }

    ...
}
```

**MyWSDL.wsdl**

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://test.mycompany.com/" name="MyWSService">

  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://test.mycompany.com/" schemaLocation="http://local-server-name/MyWSService/MyWS?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>

  <service name="MyWSService">
    <port name="MyWSPort" binding="tns:MyWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://local-server-name/MyWSService/MyWS"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: i don't mean to be rude, but is this even a question ? it starts off with "I have one final hurdle ...". and we're all supposed to know what on earth you're trying to achieve ?? it looks a bit like something i'm trying to do (that's how i got here) but as it is this question is pretty useless for the community

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but was this even a useful comment? It starts off with an insinuation and we're all supposed to know why on earth you are posting?? It sound a bit like you needed help (that's how I got here) but as far as this comment goes, it is pretty useless for the community. If you did find an answer to your issue you could post it here for the large number of other people who may have found themselves at this page for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the configuration of the GlassFish HTTP Service. I set the server's alias name to test.mycompany.com:80 for the HTTP listener being used for the web services application. Typically we have this kind of configuration in our web servers so initially I didn't even consider the application server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the WSDL?  Are you generating it by hand?  Are you generating it using wsgen with the -wsdl option?

If you're deploying with JAX-WS you shouldn't actually have to do either of those things.  Instead you should be able to go to...

```
<SERVER_URL>/<CONTEXT_LOCATION>/<SERVLET_URL>?wsdl
```

...and the JAX-WS servlet will automatically generate a wsdl on the fly with the correct location.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear...the WSDL file is being generated on the fly.